# Board game grid with fixed background

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to design a grid for a simple game and was looking up apps on the net, and came across one at http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tic-tac-toe-free/id289278457?mt=8 which seems to be something like what I have in mind.

A board with a custom background (the blackboard in this case) but which also has the cells separated by custom line separators and has well defined cells which dont overlap.

Could someone please shed some light on what kind of design / layout in Android would allow this (especially the line separating the cells). I think a GridView of several ImageViews may be used but am not sure if custom line separators could be drawn between the cells if so?

TIA

Comment: if its a fixed background why not just make the grid part of the background image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about keeping it simple and drawing cell separators right on background? If cells have uniform size, it shouldn't be too hard to align things so that GridView matches the board exactly, I think.

If on bigger screen you'd want bigger cells but not thicker cell separators, 9-patch could help there: 9-patch images can have several strechable regions on single axis and they all stretch proportionally.

Comment: hmmm... I guess I will give that a go and see how it works on different screen sizes. BTW is there any other option other than using a GridView for this?

Comment: As suggested I drew the cell separators on the background itself and tried it on the emulator with QVGA and HVGA screen sizes and so far its working as intended. :).  Hope it does on real devices as well.